# Karma can't find relative urls

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to put an iframe element inside the test, and can't figure out how to open a document that is located somewhere on the disk instead of remote website which works. So Karma is starting it's server, and doesn't see the path inside the src attribute because I guess it has different document root.

```
    element = angular.element('<iframe src="fixtures/myhtmlfile.html" ></iframe>');
   $('body').append(element);
```

Is there a way to tell karma 'look here for relative paths' ? By relative, I mean relative from the location of the actual directory where the test is located.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [`karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) within your karma.conf. See that repo for example usage. Basically, it will preprocess your html files, converting them to js files, which karma will then serve.

> This preprocessor converts HTML files into JS strings and generates Angular modules. These modules, when loaded, puts these HTML files into the $templateCache and therefore Angular won't try to fetch them from the server.

Comment: It is a little bit confusing, I'm not sure how I could reference the processed file inside the iframe's src attribute.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to tell what it is you're trying to test here. I think, though, you would leave the `src` attribute's value as a path to an html file, but then the preprocessed html (to js) would be served from the template cache.

Comment: I think I understand now, will try that. I actually just want to load an iframe element and than test what happens when there's a click event triggered by some child element of an iframe.